# How is this bracketless/braceless code valid?

Tags: c

So I came across this piece of code:

```
%:include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv<::>) <%
    printf("C program succesfully running...");
    getchar();

    return 0;
%>
```

Is this some compiler bug or is this something new I have not discovered yet because it is running without any problems.

Comment: Why is bracketless code a problem? The boggling thing is braceless code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code uses C digraphs, as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:201x, Punctuators §6.4.6:3) has this to say on the matter:

> In all aspects of the language, the six tokens
>
> ```
> <: :> <% %> %: %:%:
> ```
>
> behave, respectively, the same as the six tokens
>
> ```
> [ ] { } # ##
> ```
>
> except for their spelling.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link, It is all making sense now!

Comment: why should one do that?!

Comment: @PeterMiehle From the link of this answer: `keyboards may not have keys to cover the entire character set of the language`

Comment: @PeterMiehle Follow the Wikipedia link for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

These are punctuators and `%:` is the same as  `#` and `%>` is the same as `}` etc... The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.6` *Punctuators* says:

> In all aspects of the language, the six tokens67)
>
> > ```
> >  <:  :> <%   %> %:  %:%:
> > ```
>
> behave, respectively, the same as the six tokens
>
> > ```
> >   [   ] {    }   #   ##
> > ```

They are also sometimes refereed to as *digraphs* as we see in note `67`:

> These tokens are sometimes called ‘‘digraphs’’.

Answer (score 1):

It is all a very Zen little corner of the C language.

In the olden days, terminals and keyboards often didn't support all the characters one might want for programming; so [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) and trigraphs were introduced.

I'm surprised any modern compiler still supports them, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

[Digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), introduced in C99.

> C99 6.4.6 Punctuators
>
> In all aspects of the language, the six tokens
>
> ```
> <: :> <% %> %: %:%:
> ```
>
> behave, respectively, the same as the six tokens
>
> ```
> [ ]  {} # ##
> ```
>
> except for their spelling.